# Clear parent input by clicking child icon - Javascript (no JQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

How would one clear a `paper-input` by clicking on its child `iron-icon`?

I have the following code:

**html**

```
<paper-input id="one" class="one" on-input="doFunction">
    <iron-icon suffix icon="clear" id="clearOne" class="clear" on-click="clear"></iron-icon>
</paper-input>
```

**js**

```
clear : function(e) {
  Polymer.dom(e.currentTarget.parentNode).value = '';
}
```

I used `parentNode` after looking at the various properties held within the `currentTarget` but still no luck.

**Note: I will be using this for multiple `paper-input` elements within my page.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function definition to:

```
clear : function(e) {
  e.target.parentNode.value = '';
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: For some reason this isn't working. Debugger shows that the value is already ' ', rather than the text I have in... Any thoughts?

Comment: That works fine in `Polymer 2`. Here is the solution for `Polymer 1`: http://plnkr.co/edit/8ecrDe?p=preview

Comment: Ah that would make sense. I'm still in version 1 :-)
When you use clear-item-id, is this a defined attribute in Polymer or is it simply just made up for this demonstration?

Comment: That is just a custom attribute. You can change that.